# Naming the Rings of Flagellar Structure

Tags: cell-biology, bacteriology, cell-membrane

I will apologise ahead of my very basic question.

I just read about Flagella Structure and learned that there are 4 rings, namely "L Ring", "P Ring", "MS Ring", "C Ring".

I tried looking online for why the rings are named as such, but i could not find anything related to their naming.

I am guessing
L Ring = lipid ring?
P Ring = Periplasm ring?
MS Ring?
C Ring = Cytoplasm ring?

Thank you in advance for enlightening me.

Answer (score 1):

Your guesses are correct. More detailed, assuming you are referring to Gram-negative bacterial flagella and flagellar motor structure:

1. L ring associates with the [**L**ipopolysaccharides](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/neuroscience/lipopolysaccharide) (more general [S-layer](https://www.nature.com/articles/nrmicro3213) for archaea and Gram-positive bacteria)
2. P ring associates with the [**P**eptidoglycan](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/biochemistry-genetics-and-molecular-biology/peptidoglycan) layer
3. MS ring is embedded in the plasma **M**embrane (not sure why S maybe tran**S**membrane?)
4. C ring is a [**C**ytoplasmic](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/cytoplasm) protein attached to the MS ring acting together as the rotor of the flagellar motor

As a structural biologist here is some recommended literature on high-resolution (cryo-EM) structures of flagellar proteins:

- [3D cryo-EM imaging of bacterial flagella: Novel structural and mechanistic insights into cell motility](https://www.jbc.org/article/S0021-9258(22)00546-4/fulltext)
- [Structure of the molecular bushing of the bacterial flagellar motor](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-021-24715-3#:%7E:text=The%20basal%20body%20of%20the,stable%20rotation%20without%20much%20friction.)

[image: Molecular architecture of the bacterial flagellum.]